# argv vs. raw_input

Tags: python, argv, raw-input

I know that when using `argv` I have to type the file as an argument (ex: `python ex15.py ex15_sample.txt`) and when using `raw_input` I enter the filename as an input.

But  I can't seem to find out why one way of getting the filename would be better than another. Can someone explain why?

Comment: " I can't seem to find out why one way of getting the filename would be better than another."?  Is that the question?  The code doesn't really matter?  Are you just asking about the tradeoff between interactive and command-line?  If so, perhaps you could delete the code, since it doesn't really matter to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you generally should avoid interactive user input if it's not a key feature. In your example: Reading from stdin or the command line allows to combine different programs and run them in scripts and so on.

Imagine you execute a lot of code and sit in front of the screen waiting for the input request to come. Wasn't it better to specify all relevant information on the command line and to go and prepare a cup of coffee instead?

What you could do:

- Check if len(argv) > 1
- If so, use argv[1] as the file name
- If not, ask the user.

This adds a nice feature to your program: You can either specify the file name on the command line or enter it in an interactive mode.

Try this:

```
try:
    fn = argv[1]

except IndexError:
    fn = raw_input("filename > ")
```

Comment: I never use command line interface, even when my scripts need parameters to run, because I prefer to write them directly on the script and run it right from the editor. That way, the "working" version is automatically saved and available to reuse or modification. But it is purely a question of preference.

Comment: Imagine you had to recompile `cp` or `cd` everytime you want to change directory or copy files. And then you figure out that you also have to recompile `gcc` because of that -- you'll end up crazy :)

Comment: @wal-o-mat : that's the beauty of interpreted languages: no compile time! I love Python for that. But I recognize I should create the habit of incorporating command-line arguments in my scripts/programs. This is best practice.

Answer (score 2):

As part of command line argument input, a user can submit system calls and that could crash your program. E.g. a user can issue an ls command. The system executes that command regardless of what your program is supposed to do.